# How do I make a proper for loop with multiple conditions?

Tags: python

I am making a game and 'on key down' it moves the character (self) down..  I am trying to fix some things with collision detection. My problem in the example below is that the second line always returns True.  What I am trying to do in the second line is say "if the character collides with a widget but the characters y value is lower than half the height of the widget it's colliding withs height, then move character down.

Because it always returns True, I my character can is moving down regardless of any collision and regardless of the characters y value (it can be above the widgets midway section, and i am still able to move down).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
elif keycode[1] == 'down':
    if any(self.collide_widget(i) and self.y < (i.y+(i.height/2)) for i in listofwidgets):
        self.y -=6
        self.source='characters/lilmoney/walkdown.zip'
    elif (i.collide_point(self.x, self.top) for i in listofwidgets):
        self.source='characters/lilmoney/lilmoneyfront.png'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `any` in the `elif` statement. So, you're left with a generator, which is always true. So, change that statement to

```
elif any(i.collide_point(self.x, self.top) for i in listofwidgets):
```